# How to load external js files with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have use following method to load `html` content to my index,

```
$("#home-btn").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("views/plant.html");   
});
```

It's loading the `html` contents correctly, but i have used some external `js` files that related to the `html`'s and link the related external `js` files to my index `html`. Issue is, missing the effects form external `js` in the `html` contents that i have load. How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have the js file included in a `<script>` tag in either `plant.html` or `index.html`?

Comment: @rebecca in `index.html`

Comment: use `lazyload` method, that will be good if you are trying to load JS on click or any other event, it avoid load on first page loading time.

Comment: have you tried adding it in the plant.html? i'm assuming the effects don't take place because the content isn't there yet. do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: No any errors. I have not tried it, because I have lots of files to load like that. Is there any way to load external `js` with `html` load

Comment: According to the documentation your script should be loaded and executed if you don't use a selector expression behind your url (like your example). http://api.jquery.com/load#script-execution

Answer (score 1):

Refer your external js file with your html file as you see in the below code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/externalFile.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Load `jQuery`

```
$("#home-btn").one( "click", function() {
    console.log("You'll only see this once!");

    sendMyAjax('http://yoursite.com/script1.js');
    sendMyAjax('http://yoursite.com/script2.js');
    sendMyAjax('http://yoursite.com/script3.js');
});

function sendMyAjax(URL_address) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL_address,
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true, // or get new, fresh copy on every page load
        success: function() {
            // Callback
        }
    }
}
```

By this method the extra script will only be loaded after your click on specified location. By this way the load required to load extra JS on time of first page load can be avoided.

Comment: This is working. Can i send more scripts with this method?

Comment: yes, but i think you have use `ajax` section again. If you have time please check a plugin like lazy load, which support loading/setting multiple JS & loads those by avoid load as your requirement. I do not have those codes with me.

Comment: Thank you very much